# Generalized Linear Model in R and Python giving different result than in MATLAB

Tags: python, r, matlab, regression, statsmodels

I'm trying transcribe a function that deals with generalized linear models from MATLAB to R and Python. Currently, R and Python both give me the same answer, which differs from MATLAB's, even when given the same input.

The MATLAB code is essentially this:

```
coeffs = glmfit(X, [y ones(length(y),1)], 'binomial', 'link', 'logit');
```

Note that glmfit in matlab already adds the constant term to the X. The documentation for this function is here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/glmfit.html

In R, I have something like this:

```
model <- glm(cbind(y, array(1, length(y)))~X, family=binomial(link=logit))
coeffs <- model$coefficients
```

The documentation for glm in R is here: http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/glm.html

And in Python, I have this:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

est = sm.GLM(sm.add_constant(y, prepend=False), sm.add_constant(X), family=sm.families.Binomial()).fit()
coeffs = est.params
```

In python, the documentation is here: http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/glm.html#module-reference

According to the documentation, all of the GLM functions are using the `logit` parameter for `link`. If I had to guess, this problem could possibly be attributed to MATLAB's precision, which I have run into before. (It seems that MATLAB is not as precise as R or NumPy.) I do want to make sure, however, that I'm not just using the functions wrong.

Am I right in thinking that this is a problem with MATLAB, or am I missing some parameters/doing something wrong?

Also -- if it is important, these are the variables I'm using (I'm reading from a csv file):

X =

```
3.00000,9.10000,0.43000,-1.26000,-0.25000,0.05000,-4.01000,7.87000
4.00000,1.70000,-1.10000,0.43000,-1.26000,-17.34000,0.05000,-4.01000
5.00000,3.80000,-0.01000,-1.10000,0.43000,5.35000,-17.34000,0.05000
6.00000,0.70000,0.13000,-0.01000,-1.10000,6.03000,5.35000,-17.34000
7.00000,5.80000,0.38000,0.13000,-0.01000,18.10000,6.03000,5.35000
8.00000,8.90000,0.13000,0.38000,0.13000,-1.88000,18.10000,6.03000
9.00000,7.60000,-0.88000,0.13000,0.38000,-7.59000,-1.88000,18.10000
10.00000,4.50000,0.01000,-0.88000,0.13000,2.67000,-7.59000,-1.88000
11.00000,2.40000,0.37000,0.01000,-0.88000,12.76000,2.67000,-7.59000
12.00000,6.60000,0.60000,0.37000,0.01000,3.25000,12.76000,2.67000
13.00000,2.80000,-1.66000,0.60000,0.37000,18.67000,3.25000,12.76000
14.00000,7.20000,1.91000,-1.66000,0.60000,-0.37000,18.67000,3.25000
15.00000,4.00000,0.78000,1.91000,-1.66000,-8.18000,-0.37000,18.67000
16.00000,7.00000,-0.81000,0.78000,1.91000,8.86000,-8.18000,-0.37000
17.00000,0.50000,0.33000,-0.81000,0.78000,-12.55000,8.86000,-8.18000
18.00000,4.00000,1.17000,0.33000,-0.81000,-10.02000,-12.55000,8.86000
19.00000,7.10000,0.20000,1.17000,0.33000,5.50000,-10.02000,-12.55000
20.00000,3.20000,0.12000,0.20000,1.17000,-20.33000,5.50000,-10.02000
3.00000,0.70000,-1.26000,-0.96000,0.88000,-12.24000,7.18000,0.31000
4.00000,1.60000,-0.70000,-1.26000,-0.96000,-1.32000,-12.24000,7.18000
5.00000,8.00000,1.98000,-0.70000,-1.26000,6.75000,-1.32000,-12.24000
6.00000,3.40000,0.80000,1.98000,-0.70000,17.24000,6.75000,-1.32000
7.00000,8.00000,-1.09000,0.80000,1.98000,-7.76000,17.24000,6.75000
8.00000,7.30000,-0.59000,-1.09000,0.80000,-2.04000,-7.76000,17.24000
9.00000,7.70000,0.69000,-0.59000,-1.09000,7.18000,-2.04000,-7.76000
10.00000,6.60000,0.09000,0.69000,-0.59000,-1.75000,7.18000,-2.04000
11.00000,0.10000,0.10000,0.09000,0.69000,1.37000,-1.75000,7.18000
12.00000,5.80000,0.18000,0.10000,0.09000,14.02000,1.37000,-1.75000
13.00000,9.90000,-1.36000,0.18000,0.10000,-3.16000,14.02000,1.37000
14.00000,1.30000,-0.26000,-1.36000,0.18000,6.47000,-3.16000,14.02000
15.00000,8.40000,-0.52000,-0.26000,-1.36000,-7.12000,6.47000,-3.16000
16.00000,7.40000,-0.66000,-0.52000,-0.26000,-1.73000,-7.12000,6.47000
17.00000,8.30000,-0.63000,-0.66000,-0.52000,11.65000,-1.73000,-7.12000
18.00000,6.70000,-1.04000,-0.63000,-0.66000,13.63000,11.65000,-1.73000
19.00000,5.80000,-1.25000,-1.04000,-0.63000,-14.71000,13.63000,11.65000
20.00000,3.20000,-1.37000,-1.25000,-1.04000,-3.60000,-14.71000,13.63000
3.00000,2.30000,-1.16000,-0.19000,-0.70000,8.41000,0.18000,-4.08000
4.00000,1.90000,1.11000,-1.16000,-0.19000,-0.00000,8.41000,0.18000
5.00000,6.40000,0.12000,1.11000,-1.16000,17.86000,-0.00000,8.41000
6.00000,3.90000,1.30000,0.12000,1.11000,1.12000,17.86000,-0.00000
7.00000,0.80000,-0.63000,1.30000,0.12000,-1.33000,1.12000,17.86000
8.00000,7.60000,-0.21000,-0.63000,1.30000,22.26000,-1.33000,1.12000
9.00000,0.90000,1.47000,-0.21000,-0.63000,-14.10000,22.26000,-1.33000
10.00000,5.10000,0.60000,1.47000,-0.21000,13.36000,-14.10000,22.26000
11.00000,6.40000,-1.41000,0.60000,1.47000,-5.37000,13.36000,-14.10000
12.00000,3.30000,-0.97000,-1.41000,0.60000,6.47000,-5.37000,13.36000
13.00000,8.80000,1.82000,-0.97000,-1.41000,8.82000,6.47000,-5.37000
14.00000,9.90000,1.80000,1.82000,-0.97000,5.63000,8.82000,6.47000
15.00000,3.40000,-0.60000,1.80000,1.82000,5.02000,5.63000,8.82000
16.00000,5.90000,-1.14000,-0.60000,1.80000,10.93000,5.02000,5.63000
17.00000,3.00000,0.77000,-1.14000,-0.60000,-2.12000,10.93000,5.02000
18.00000,1.60000,1.69000,0.77000,-1.14000,-2.89000,-2.12000,10.93000
19.00000,1.10000,-0.07000,1.69000,0.77000,-2.78000,-2.89000,-2.12000
20.00000,0.70000,-0.66000,-0.07000,1.69000,2.82000,-2.78000,-2.89000
3.00000,1.30000,-0.72000,1.12000,1.41000,4.24000,5.35000,-0.62000
4.00000,4.80000,-1.18000,-0.72000,1.12000,8.91000,4.24000,5.35000
5.00000,1.30000,-0.44000,-1.18000,-0.72000,1.15000,8.91000,4.24000
6.00000,8.90000,-0.42000,-0.44000,-1.18000,11.64000,1.15000,8.91000
7.00000,6.20000,0.06000,-0.42000,-0.44000,20.74000,11.64000,1.15000
8.00000,6.60000,1.83000,0.06000,-0.42000,21.14000,20.74000,11.64000
9.00000,2.80000,1.50000,1.83000,0.06000,-16.67000,21.14000,20.74000
10.00000,8.70000,-1.72000,1.50000,1.83000,9.86000,-16.67000,21.14000
11.00000,6.90000,-1.51000,-1.72000,1.50000,14.44000,9.86000,-16.67000
12.00000,1.80000,-1.10000,-1.51000,-1.72000,3.64000,14.44000,9.86000
13.00000,4.30000,-1.34000,-1.10000,-1.51000,13.78000,3.64000,14.44000
14.00000,4.90000,-0.31000,-1.34000,-1.10000,-2.43000,13.78000,3.64000
15.00000,2.50000,1.69000,-0.31000,-1.34000,5.85000,-2.43000,13.78000
16.00000,1.70000,0.67000,1.69000,-0.31000,-0.94000,5.85000,-2.43000
17.00000,8.00000,1.23000,0.67000,1.69000,-2.19000,-0.94000,5.85000
18.00000,1.40000,0.63000,1.23000,0.67000,14.29000,-2.19000,-0.94000
19.00000,5.00000,1.10000,0.63000,1.23000,7.65000,14.29000,-2.19000
20.00000,4.10000,-0.13000,1.10000,0.63000,3.03000,7.65000,14.29000
3.00000,3.70000,-0.79000,-1.32000,-0.62000,-5.73000,0.93000,-0.62000
4.00000,0.90000,1.56000,-0.79000,-1.32000,3.27000,-5.73000,0.93000
5.00000,6.90000,2.39000,1.56000,-0.79000,11.63000,3.27000,-5.73000
6.00000,0.20000,1.17000,2.39000,1.56000,2.61000,11.63000,3.27000
7.00000,2.30000,-0.83000,1.17000,2.39000,18.57000,2.61000,11.63000
8.00000,0.10000,0.08000,-0.83000,1.17000,2.48000,18.57000,2.61000
9.00000,0.80000,-0.52000,0.08000,-0.83000,-2.11000,2.48000,18.57000
10.00000,3.40000,0.47000,-0.52000,0.08000,-5.58000,-2.11000,2.48000
11.00000,3.30000,-1.37000,0.47000,-0.52000,-5.09000,-5.58000,-2.11000
12.00000,7.70000,-0.54000,-1.37000,0.47000,-13.45000,-5.09000,-5.58000
13.00000,7.80000,2.62000,-0.54000,-1.37000,13.67000,-13.45000,-5.09000
14.00000,3.50000,0.91000,2.62000,-0.54000,-10.03000,13.67000,-13.45000
15.00000,4.40000,-0.73000,0.91000,2.62000,7.27000,-10.03000,13.67000
16.00000,0.50000,0.53000,-0.73000,0.91000,-5.44000,7.27000,-10.03000
17.00000,4.50000,-0.80000,0.53000,-0.73000,7.60000,-5.44000,7.27000
18.00000,7.90000,0.01000,-0.80000,0.53000,-11.30000,7.60000,-5.44000
19.00000,6.30000,0.42000,0.01000,-0.80000,9.38000,-11.30000,7.60000
20.00000,2.70000,0.13000,0.42000,0.01000,3.55000,9.38000,-11.30000
```

and y =

```
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
1.00000
1.00000
0.00000
1.00000
1.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
1.00000
0.00000
1.00000
0.00000
0.00000
1.00000
1.00000
0.00000
1.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
1.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
1.00000
1.00000
0.00000
0.00000
1.00000
0.00000
1.00000
1.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
1.00000
1.00000
0.00000
1.00000
0.00000
1.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
1.00000
0.00000
0.00000
1.00000
1.00000
0.00000
1.00000
1.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
1.00000
0.00000
0.00000
0.00000
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: I added the documentation for GLM in Python and R.

Comment: In R, the response for a binomial glm can be a vector of 0's and 1's (if working with a Bernoulli variable where the binomial sample size is 1) or a matrix of the successes and failures.  As you've coded it, your response is a matrix of successes and *number of attempts*.  Try changing your response to either `y` or `cbind(y, 1 - y)`.

Comment: I did that, and it worked. I also tried doing the same thing in Python and it also fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to aosmith, I was able to find the solution --

my R code was changed to :

```
y <- cbind(y, 1-y)
model <- glm(y~X, family=binomial(link=logit))
coeffs <- model$coeffs
```

and my Python code was changed to:

```
est = sm.GLM(np.vstack([y, 1-y]).T, sm.add_constant(X), family=sm.families.Binomial()).fit()
coeffs = est.params
```

Thank you!